# Rails couldn't find a valid model for - but association exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a polymorphic table in rails `MetaFieldsData` which also belongs to a table `MetaFields`

```
class MetaFieldsData < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :meta_field
end
```

```
class MetaField < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :meta_fields_data
end
```

One model which is connected to the polymorphic table is called `orders`:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  ...
  has_many :meta_fields_data, as: :owner

  ...
```

`owner` is my association class (the same what is `imageable` from the official [RoR guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations))
Now I see a strange behaviour when I want to create a record on a the `Order` model:

`MetaFieldsData.create(owner: order, meta_field: some_meta_field)`

It throws:

```
NameError Exception: Rails couldn't find a valid model for MetaFieldsDatum association.
Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.
```

What is weird is that there is no class `MetaFieldsDatum` (note the typo here, coming from Rails). I searched all my code and there is no typo in there, also not in the class name definition.

This makes it impossible for me to create an actual `MetaFieldsData` on this table as Rails seems to interpret the naming wrong.
What could possibly be wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but my solution was different.

I had a typo in my `belongs_to` model which invalidated the model.

I discovered it was an invalid model by trying to access it in the console. Because it was invalid, Rails didn't load it and subsequently couldn't find it.

The error disappeared when I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

`Datum` is used as a plural form of `data`. Notice that you have `has_many :meta_fields_data` and if you would to change that into a singular it would also be `has_one :meta_fields_data`.
This is called inflection and it is a way of detecting plural forms of words, you can read up on how rails does it here https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html

In general you can either simply obide to what the error tells you and use `datum` in relationship name (specify class_name if you do so), or define your own inflection